# Deltoid shaped succulent leaves

Tags: identification, succulents

Another succulent found in a greenhouse without a tag in the Gobi desert, though likely originating elsewhere in the world.

[image]

And with Bamboo's ID, I found an example online of this plant flowering.

[image: Isuzu jade plant in flower]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Fenestraria aurantiaca, commonly known as Baby Toes - they sometimes have quite pinkish tinges round the edges. Native to South Africa https://shopaltmanplants.com/products/fenestraria-aurantiaca-baby-toes.

Comment: Isuzu jade seems to the other name.

Comment: I guess it's a Fenestraria because it's a window plant where light enters the window and causes internal photosynthesis?

Comment: Yep-  from the Latin 'fenestra' - still in use to an extent today, fenetre in French, fenestration for windows generally in English and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Correctly identified above. They flower (in North America) fairly profusely in late winter/spring. They flower over a period of weeks. They need a fair amount of water and plenty of sun. They spread pretty quickly for a succulent. I've had a few and enjoyed them. There are pink, white and yellow flowered variants.

Comment: What temperatures range?

Comment: Good question. I've always had mine outside in Phoenix, AZ. It gets down into the mid-20s F (4 C) for short periods during winter and up above 110 F (43 C) in summer. They are fairly hardy, but there is probably more specific information online. I've always been more of a cactus guy with a few succulents. Fenesteria are generally quite available in my area.